# Delete data from Redis when the Socket.io server crashes

Tags: redis, socket.io

I am working on a multi-node socket.io app that uses Redis to store information about the devices connected.

When a user connects to the app, I store in Redis a hash with userID:socketID and another has with computerID:socketID. This allows me to quickly find out if a user is connected or if a specific computer is connected. However, if for some reason my socket.io server crashes I need this information to be deleted from Redis automatically. Also, if the Redis server crashes I need this deleted automatically. I guess I could use socket.io "Rooms", but I don't know how they would work in a multi-node environment.

I also have a tiny piece of information that needs persistence, so it is important that piece of information does not get deleted if any of the server crashes.

Is there a way to automatically delete ***specific data*** from Redis if my socket.io server, or the Redis server itself, go down?

Comment: If your Redis server is crashing that's a big issue. Using something like MemoryStore at Google will give you a high-availability Redis server that is duplicated automatically. One server crashing won't matter.